# Does the return keyword have a role to stop the execution of a method? Does it help control the code? Isn't it an output command?

Tags: java

I've always had a doubt about the `return` keyword. After doing some research, I understood that this keyword ends the execution of a function (method), but I still don't know if this is something I should accept as an answer, so I would like to hear the opinion of someone who has more knowledge and can make sure this is correct or not.

I did a test in order to see if the return really ends the execution of a function

**Example 1**

```
public static int addition(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

    return sum;
}
```

When invoking this method, it will run successfully.

**Example 2**

```
public static int addition(int num1, int num2)
{
    int sum = num1 + num2;

    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);

    return sum;

    //Let's see if return really stop the execution of the function

    System.out.println("A quick test.");
}
```

The function will not be executed, because the return ends the execution of the function and, after the return, there is the presence of an output command (which will not be executed, as the return has already finished the block of instructions).
This way, I came to the conclusion that the return is not there to execute an output command, but for the sake of controlling the return type that the function will have and also to finish the method execution. That is, if a function is of type integer, and receives integer parameters, it must return an integer, but this return will not print anything on the screen, but will finish the execution of the block of instructions.

My question may seem far from succinct, but I wish someone could tell me if my line of reasoning makes sense.
I don't just want to be a "programmer", I want to learn deeply about the subject. Taking a subject halfway home is not something I intend. So if you approve of my way of thinking, consider helping me with this doubt.

Comment: "The function will not be executed" that code simply won't compile, because the print after the return is unreachable. Whatever conclusions you have reached about that code other than it doesn't compile are wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The return statement causes an immediate return from the method it appears in.

It's a flow-of-control statement.  It may (if followed by an expression) also establish the value to be returned by the method, but always it terminates execution of the active instance of the method.  It has nothing to do with "output".

Editorial: that's elementary stuff, and therefore I expect it must appear in every single Java textbook.

So, in respect of

> consider helping me with this doubt.

I'd suggest reading a textbook or two.  Seriously, not meant as a put-down. The empirical method is not always the best, and online Q&A sites definitely aren't.

Comment: "The return statement causes an immediate return from the method it appears in." No, it causes an _attempt_ to immediately return. It can be stopped by a return or throw in a finally.

Comment: Right. But don't you think that might be a little too detailed for someone who doesn't yet understand that 'return' means the statement after the return doesn't get executed?  Lessons should be adapted to the knowledge of the student, not designed to illuminate the erudition of the teacher.

Comment: @user16532363 the risk of such simplification - particularly where OP is clearly seeking a deep understanding - is that it teaches things which need to be unlearned sooner or later. By all means skip the explanation of the details (e.g. "causes an immediate return (unless there is a `finally` involved)", but at least point out that the explanation isn't the whole story.